# Gas range burner won't ignite in the morning

Tags: gas, stove, range

one of the burners on my gas range won't throw a spark when first used in the morning. If, however, I light it up with a match, it will start throwing a spark both while burning as well as if I turn the burner off and restart it the normal way (without a match). Would really appreciate any advice you can give. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Often the spark from the electric igniter is redirected and cannot ignite the burner gas. This could happen if there is any moisture on or near the electrode. Do you wipe down the stove in the evening, leaving it damp? Do you boil water on that burner in the evening, potentially causing dripping condensation that could be getting the area wet?

Another common cause is the gas port in the burner assembly. There is (usually) a small "pilot" port near the electrode that directs a small amount of gas to the electrode area, for easy (non-explosive) ignition. Ensure the port is free of corrosion and debris. This scenario does not seem to align with your "morning only" intermittent issue, however.